# Multiple checkboxes for multiple paths of one SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, checkbox, path

So I have made this code (when you click on the face it checks a checkbox) :

```css
.mySVG input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
.mySVG label{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.mySVG svg{
    fill:#F9F7F7;
    stroke: #112D4E;
    stroke-width: 5;
    width:100px;
}
.mySVG input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label .Vsvg{
    fill: #3F72AF;
}
```

```html
<div class="mySVG">
  <input type="checkbox" id="x" name="x">
  <label for="x">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 290.5 366.2">
          <path id="V1svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M249.3,38.1c-6.5,8.6-14.9,21.8-14.1,25.6c0.2,1.1-10.7,0.1-14.4,0.1c-3.4-0.1-8-0.2-11.3,0.2c-2.8,0.3-9.1,1.2-9.1,1.2l-10.2,2.8  l-11,4.1l-12.7,5.2l-8.6,4.5l-8.6,6.5l-8.2,7.3l-4.5,8.2l-2.8,9l-4.5,19.9l-2.4,8.2l-2,4.5l-0.8,3.6l-0.8,7.3l-0.8,9.4l-0.8,4.9  l-2.4,3.6l-6.9,3.2c0,0-3.3,0.2-4.5,0.8c-0.5,0.2-1,0.7-1.2,1.2c-0.2,0.6,0.1,1.5-0.2,1.9c-0.6,1-1.8,1.5-3.1,2.2  c-1.4,0.7-2.4,1.2-3.6,1.2c-0.7,0-2.1,0.1-2.8,0.1c-1,0-2.3,0-3.2,0c-1.1,0-2.6-0.2-3.6-0.4c-0.9-0.2-1.9-0.8-2.8-0.8  c-1.2,0-1.5-0.4-1.7-0.1c-1.7,1.5-2.7,2.8-2.7,2.8l-3.2,2.8l-5.7,6.9l-8.6,13.5l-3.2,4.5l-7.8,2.8l-7.8,1.6l-4.5,4.5l-3.6,3.6  c0,0-2.1,3.6-3.6,3.6c-1.8,0.2-4.9-3.2-4.9-3.2l-1.6-2.4l-0.4-2l-0.4-3.2c0,0-0.2-1.5,0-2c0.2-1.2,1.6-3.6,1.6-3.6l2-3.2  c0,0,1.2-1,1.8-1.6c0.6-0.5,1.9-1.7,1.9-1.7l1.6-1.6l1.6-1.6c0,0,3.4-6,4.9-8.6c2.7-4.8,9.4-15.9,9.4-15.9l3.2-4.9l1.6-2l2.8-3.6  l0.4-3.6v-3.6v-2.4l-1.3-3.1l-2-4.1l-0.8-4.9v-4.1l3.2-10.2l6.1-14.6c0,0,2.1-5.3,3.1-7.8c1-2.4,3.1-8.2,3.1-8.2l7.3-17.9l6.9-9.8  l6.5-8.2l12.3-7.8l14.3-8.2l23.2-8.6L158,39l28.2-1.6l20.4-0.8l27.3-0.8l9.4,0.3C243.3,36.1,250.5,36.5,249.3,38.1z"/>
          <path id="V2svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M35.1,230.6l6.5-7.1c0,0,2.2-2.4,3.3-3.5c0.4-0.4,1-1.2,1.5-1.3c2-0.5,7.6-1.5,7.6-1.5l8.2-2.8l12.4-19.5l5.3-5.7l5.3-4.9l1-0.6  l5.7,1.6l6.9-0.2h1.9l4.7-2.3c0,0,0.9-0.9,1-1.5c0.2-0.4,0-1.5,0-1.5s0.3-1,0.6-1.3c0.7-0.6,3.1-1,3.1-1s2-0.2,2.7-0.4  c1.9-0.6,4.5-1.5,6.1-3.1c1-1,2.2-2.5,2.6-3.9c0.7-2.2,1.2-7.5,1.2-7.5l1-13.2l1.5-5.1l1.6-3.6l1.6-5.1l1.6-6.3l2-9.4  c0,0,2.6-11.5,4.5-16.1c0.6-1.5,1.8-3.1,2.5-4.5c0.6-1,1.2-2.7,2-3.6c1.2-1.5,5.1-4.3,5.1-4.3l3.6-3.6c0,0,2.7-2.7,2.8-2.3  c0.6,1.5,0,8.4,0,8.4l-0.4,2.8l-0.4,2.3l-0.2,7.1l0.4,9.2l0.8,3.5c0,0,0.5,4.2,0.7,6.1c0.2,1.6,0.9,5.5,0.9,5.5l0.2,6.9l0.4,8.8v9.2  v11l-1.2,11c0,0-0.6,3.4-1,4.4c-0.5,1.1-0.8,4.1-0.8,4.1s-1.5,4.8-2.2,6.8c-1,2.9-4,9.3-4,9.3l-3.2,6.9l-2,4.1l-2,5.5l-2.4,8.8  l-3.6,9c0,0-2.7,4.7-3.8,6.9c-0.6,1-1.6,2.3-2.3,3.2c-0.9,0.9-2,1.9-3.1,2.7c-1,0.7-3.1,1.5-4.3,2c-3.4,1.2-11,2.9-11,2.9l-7.9,1.9  l-8.2,0.8l-5.7,1.2c0,0-1.7,0.3-2.4,0.4c-0.4,0-1-0.2-1.2,0c-0.8,0.7,0.8,2.5,0.4,3.6c-0.2,0.6-1.9-0.6-1.9-0.6l-1.9-0.4l-2.8,0.4  l-6.7,0.4H67l-2.4,0.8l-2,0.6l-2.4,0.6l-3.2-0.2c0,0-2.3,0-3.2,0c-0.8,0-1.9,0-2.7,0c-0.2,0-0.6,0.2-0.8,0c-0.6-0.4-1-1.5-1.2-2.3  c-0.1-0.3,0-1,0-1s-0.2-0.7-0.4-1c-0.2-0.4-1.2-1-1.2-1s-0.8-0.3-1-0.6c-0.2-0.3-0.1-1.4-0.1-1.4s0-1,0.1-1.5  c0.2-0.7,0.7-1.9,0.7-2.3c0.1-0.6,0.8-2.2,0.8-2.4c0.2-1,1.9-8.6,1.5-11.6c-0.1-0.7-0.3-1.5-0.5-2.1c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.8-0.2-1.1  c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.7c0-0.1-0.3-0.6-0.5-0.8c-0.1-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.6-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.7-0.7-1-0.7c-3.1,0.1-1.1,0-1.3,0  c-1.3,0.1-1.9-0.1-3.1,0.4c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.4c-0.6,0.2-1.9-0.2-1.9-0.2s-1.6-0.2-2.3-0.5c-0.7-0.3-2.2-1.7-2.2-1.7"/>
          <path id="V3svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M235.1,64.5c-1-1.1-5.2-0.2-5.2-0.2l-6.9-0.2l-8.7-0.4l-6.7,0.4l-7.7,1.1l-10.4,2.7l-13.7,5.4l-8.9,3.7l-5.7,3.1l-3.3,1.7l-2.6,1.9  l-1.7,1.5l-0.9,0.3l0.6,3.1l-0.4,5l-1,6.3v8.3l0.4,6.5l0.9,3.6l0.2,2.7l0.3,2.2l0.4,3l0.9,4.1v5.2l0.4,12.8l0.2,12.1l-0.2,6l-0.6,5  l-0.7,6.1l-1,4.6l-0.9,4.3l-3.7,10.3l-5,11l-3.1,6.1l-2.7,8.7l-1.3,5.2l-2.3,4.8l-2,5l-2.8,4.8l-2.8,4l-3.1,2.7l-6.1,2.2l-10,2.6  l-5.7,1.3l-5.2,0.6l-5.2,0.7c0,0-3.6,1-5.2,1.1c-0.9,0.1-2.4-0.6-3,0.2c-0.7,0.9,1.5,2.9,0.7,3.7c-0.4,0.4-1.7-0.3-1.7-0.3  s-1.1-0.6-1.7-0.7c-0.6-0.1-2.3,0.3-2.3,0.3l-6,0.6h-2.6H67l-6.5,1.9l-5.1-0.1c0,0-1.5-0.2-1.9,0.1c-0.5,0.4-0.8,1.1-1.3,1.5  c-0.2,0.2-0.8,1.2-1,1.5c-0.6,0.6-1.1,2.7-1.1,3.1c-0.2,1.2-0.6,3-0.6,4.3c0,1-0.1,1.9-0.2,2.2c-0.1,0.5,0.1,2.8,0.4,3.1  c0.4,0.4,1.4,0.3,1.9,0.6c0.4,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.9,0.9c0.2,0.1,0.2,0,0.4,0.1c0.5,0.2,0.9,0.8,1.1,1.3c0.5,1,1.4,1.6,2.2,2.4  c0.6,0.7,1.3,1.8,1.7,2.6c0.2,0.5,0.6,1.1,0.7,1.7c0.2,1,0.1,2.3-0.3,3.1c-0.2,0.7-1.1,1.5-1.5,2.2c-0.8,1.4-1.5,3.4-2.3,4.8  c-0.4,0.7-1,1.7-1.3,2.4c-0.2,0.6-0.7,1.4-0.8,2.2c-0.2,1.4,0.2,5.1,0.2,5.1v2.2c0,0,0.1,1.3,0.2,1.8c0.2,0.6,0.6,1.2,0.6,1.8  c0,1-0.2,2.3,0,3.3c0.1,0.5,0.6,1,0.7,1.5c0.2,0.7-0.1,1.7,0.2,2.4c0.2,0.8,0.8,1.9,1.3,2.6c0.4,0.6,1,1.5,1.5,2c1,1,2.7,2,4,2.7  c1,0.6,2.3,1.3,3.4,1.5c1.9,0.5,6.7,0.4,6.7,0.4h5c0,0,5.6,0.3,7.8-0.5c0.9-0.3,2.5-1.6,2.5-1.6s1.1-1.3,1.7-1.7  c0.8-0.6,2-1.3,3-1.5c0.9-0.3,2.2-0.3,3.1-0.4c2.4-0.2,5.7,0.3,8.2-0.2c0.6-0.2,1.5-0.6,2.2-0.9c1.6-0.5,5.4-1,5.4-1l6.3-0.7  l10.4-2.8l6.3-2.4l9.1-4.6l6-2.8l3.7-2.6l4.6-3.4l4.4-4.1l3-3.3l2.7-3.9l2.6-6.1c0,0,1.8-7.5,3-10.7c0.5-1.3,1.9-4.3,1.9-4.3  s1.4-2.3,1.8-3.3c1.1-2.7,2-6.5,3.1-9.2c0.8-2.1,3.1-6.9,3.1-6.9l1.7-3.4l2.3-3.7c0,0,1.6-2.7,2.3-3.9c1-1.5,2.1-3.6,3.1-5.2  c1-1.5,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8s1.6-2.5,2.4-3.4c1.5-1.6,3.6-3.6,5.2-5c1-0.7,2.3-1.4,3.3-2c1-0.6,2.6-1.4,3.7-1.9c1.7-0.7,5.7-2.3,5.7-2.3  l2.8-2c0,0,1.2-0.6,1.5-1c0.2-0.5-0.2-1.2,0-1.7c0.2-0.3,0.6-0.8,0.9-0.7c0.4,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.6,1.1c0.2,0.4,0.7,0.7,1.2,0.8  c0.8,0.2,0.8-1.3,1-2c0.4-1,0.4-1.9,0.4-2.7c0.1-1.6,0-2.7,0.1-4.5c0-0.5-0.6-1.9-0.6-2.3c0.1-0.9-0.9-3.1-0.9-3.1l-1.1-3  c0,0-0.8-1.9-1.1-2.7c-0.2-0.5-0.7-1.1-0.7-1.7c0-0.4,0.3-1.1,0.7-1.1c0.2,0,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.6c0.5,0.6,1.5,1.9,1.5,1.9l1.7,1  c0,0,1.6-0.1,2.3-0.3c0.6-0.2,1.4-1,2-1.3c0.6-0.2,1.5-0.2,2-0.6c0.3-0.2,0.4-0.8,0.7-1c0.6-0.3,1.6,0,2.3,0.2  c0.5,0.2,1.5,0.7,1.5,0.7s1.5,0.1,2-0.2c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.6,1-1c0.2-0.5-0.1-1.3,0-1.9c0.1-0.5,0.3-1,0.6-1.5c0.2-0.3,0.8-0.4,1-0.7  c0.2-0.3,0-0.8,0-1.1c0-2.3,0.2-7.6,0.2-7.6s-0.3-3.6,0.2-5.2c0.2-0.5,0.4-1.2,0.9-1.5c0.4-0.2,1.2,0.3,1.5,0  c0.6-0.5,0.4-2.6,0.4-2.6s0.2-4.4-0.2-6c-0.2-0.6-1-1.3-1.7-1.5c-0.5-0.2-1.1,0.2-1.5,0.3c-0.5,0-1.1,0-1.5-0.2  c-0.5-0.2-0.9-1-1.5-1c-0.6,0-1.1,0.8-1.7,1c-0.2,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.7,0c-0.4-0.3-0.4-1.2-0.4-1.7c-0.1-1,0.9-3.5,0-3.1  c-0.2,0.1-1,0-1.3-0.3c-0.6-0.6-0.4-2.7-0.4-2.7l-0.6-2.5l-2.4-19.3l-0.2-4.1l-0.2-4.4l-0.5-7.7l0.2-6.9l0.2-7.3l0.9-8.2l1.3-7.7  l0.9-6.9c0,0,0.5-3.7,1-5.2c0.4-1.4,1.5-3,2-4.3c0.4-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.1-2.2C235.2,65.6,235.8,65.3,235.1,64.5z"/>
      </svg>
  </label>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to make 3 different checkboxes that would check or uncheck when I click on one of the 3 pathes that make the face. Like for exemple

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 290.5 366.2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="x" name="x">
  <label for="x">
    <path id="V1svg" class="Vsvg" d="..."/>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="y" name="y">
  <label for="y">
    <path id="V2svg" class="Vsvg" d="..."/>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="z" name="z">
  <label for="z">
    <path id="V3svg" class="Vsvg" d=" ... "/>
  </label>
</svg>
```

I haven't figured out how to do this ? Do you know a simple whay to do so ?

Comment: make 3 SVG on the top of each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Michael Mullany pointed out `pointer-events: visiblePainted` applied on the path elements will do the trick.

You will also need to disable pointer events on labels:

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
}

.mySVG {
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
}

.mySVG label {
  cursor: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.Vsvg use {
  pointer-events: visiblePainted;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySVG input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.mySVG svg {
  fill: #f9f7f7;
  stroke: #112d4e;
  stroke-width: 5;
  width: 100px;
}

.mySVG input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .Vsvg {
  fill: #3f72af;
}
```

```html
<div class="mySVG">
  <input type="checkbox" id="x" name="x">
  <label for="x">
     <svg class="Vsvg" viewBox="0 0 290.5 366.2">
        <use href="#V1svg" />
    </svg>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="y" name="y">
  <label for="y">
      <svg class="Vsvg" viewBox="0 0 290.5 366.2">
        <use href="#V2svg" />
    </svg>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="z" name="z">
  <label for="z">
      <svg class="Vsvg" viewBox="0 0 290.5 366.2">
        <use href="#V3svg" />
    </svg>
  </label>


  <svg class="svgAsset" viewBox="0 0 290.5 366.2">
        <defs>
          <path id="V1svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M249.3,38.1c-6.5,8.6-14.9,21.8-14.1,25.6c0.2,1.1-10.7,0.1-14.4,0.1c-3.4-0.1-8-0.2-11.3,0.2c-2.8,0.3-9.1,1.2-9.1,1.2l-10.2,2.8  l-11,4.1l-12.7,5.2l-8.6,4.5l-8.6,6.5l-8.2,7.3l-4.5,8.2l-2.8,9l-4.5,19.9l-2.4,8.2l-2,4.5l-0.8,3.6l-0.8,7.3l-0.8,9.4l-0.8,4.9  l-2.4,3.6l-6.9,3.2c0,0-3.3,0.2-4.5,0.8c-0.5,0.2-1,0.7-1.2,1.2c-0.2,0.6,0.1,1.5-0.2,1.9c-0.6,1-1.8,1.5-3.1,2.2  c-1.4,0.7-2.4,1.2-3.6,1.2c-0.7,0-2.1,0.1-2.8,0.1c-1,0-2.3,0-3.2,0c-1.1,0-2.6-0.2-3.6-0.4c-0.9-0.2-1.9-0.8-2.8-0.8  c-1.2,0-1.5-0.4-1.7-0.1c-1.7,1.5-2.7,2.8-2.7,2.8l-3.2,2.8l-5.7,6.9l-8.6,13.5l-3.2,4.5l-7.8,2.8l-7.8,1.6l-4.5,4.5l-3.6,3.6  c0,0-2.1,3.6-3.6,3.6c-1.8,0.2-4.9-3.2-4.9-3.2l-1.6-2.4l-0.4-2l-0.4-3.2c0,0-0.2-1.5,0-2c0.2-1.2,1.6-3.6,1.6-3.6l2-3.2  c0,0,1.2-1,1.8-1.6c0.6-0.5,1.9-1.7,1.9-1.7l1.6-1.6l1.6-1.6c0,0,3.4-6,4.9-8.6c2.7-4.8,9.4-15.9,9.4-15.9l3.2-4.9l1.6-2l2.8-3.6  l0.4-3.6v-3.6v-2.4l-1.3-3.1l-2-4.1l-0.8-4.9v-4.1l3.2-10.2l6.1-14.6c0,0,2.1-5.3,3.1-7.8c1-2.4,3.1-8.2,3.1-8.2l7.3-17.9l6.9-9.8  l6.5-8.2l12.3-7.8l14.3-8.2l23.2-8.6L158,39l28.2-1.6l20.4-0.8l27.3-0.8l9.4,0.3C243.3,36.1,250.5,36.5,249.3,38.1z"/>
          <path id="V2svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M35.1,230.6l6.5-7.1c0,0,2.2-2.4,3.3-3.5c0.4-0.4,1-1.2,1.5-1.3c2-0.5,7.6-1.5,7.6-1.5l8.2-2.8l12.4-19.5l5.3-5.7l5.3-4.9l1-0.6  l5.7,1.6l6.9-0.2h1.9l4.7-2.3c0,0,0.9-0.9,1-1.5c0.2-0.4,0-1.5,0-1.5s0.3-1,0.6-1.3c0.7-0.6,3.1-1,3.1-1s2-0.2,2.7-0.4  c1.9-0.6,4.5-1.5,6.1-3.1c1-1,2.2-2.5,2.6-3.9c0.7-2.2,1.2-7.5,1.2-7.5l1-13.2l1.5-5.1l1.6-3.6l1.6-5.1l1.6-6.3l2-9.4  c0,0,2.6-11.5,4.5-16.1c0.6-1.5,1.8-3.1,2.5-4.5c0.6-1,1.2-2.7,2-3.6c1.2-1.5,5.1-4.3,5.1-4.3l3.6-3.6c0,0,2.7-2.7,2.8-2.3  c0.6,1.5,0,8.4,0,8.4l-0.4,2.8l-0.4,2.3l-0.2,7.1l0.4,9.2l0.8,3.5c0,0,0.5,4.2,0.7,6.1c0.2,1.6,0.9,5.5,0.9,5.5l0.2,6.9l0.4,8.8v9.2  v11l-1.2,11c0,0-0.6,3.4-1,4.4c-0.5,1.1-0.8,4.1-0.8,4.1s-1.5,4.8-2.2,6.8c-1,2.9-4,9.3-4,9.3l-3.2,6.9l-2,4.1l-2,5.5l-2.4,8.8  l-3.6,9c0,0-2.7,4.7-3.8,6.9c-0.6,1-1.6,2.3-2.3,3.2c-0.9,0.9-2,1.9-3.1,2.7c-1,0.7-3.1,1.5-4.3,2c-3.4,1.2-11,2.9-11,2.9l-7.9,1.9  l-8.2,0.8l-5.7,1.2c0,0-1.7,0.3-2.4,0.4c-0.4,0-1-0.2-1.2,0c-0.8,0.7,0.8,2.5,0.4,3.6c-0.2,0.6-1.9-0.6-1.9-0.6l-1.9-0.4l-2.8,0.4  l-6.7,0.4H67l-2.4,0.8l-2,0.6l-2.4,0.6l-3.2-0.2c0,0-2.3,0-3.2,0c-0.8,0-1.9,0-2.7,0c-0.2,0-0.6,0.2-0.8,0c-0.6-0.4-1-1.5-1.2-2.3  c-0.1-0.3,0-1,0-1s-0.2-0.7-0.4-1c-0.2-0.4-1.2-1-1.2-1s-0.8-0.3-1-0.6c-0.2-0.3-0.1-1.4-0.1-1.4s0-1,0.1-1.5  c0.2-0.7,0.7-1.9,0.7-2.3c0.1-0.6,0.8-2.2,0.8-2.4c0.2-1,1.9-8.6,1.5-11.6c-0.1-0.7-0.3-1.5-0.5-2.1c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.8-0.2-1.1  c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.7c0-0.1-0.3-0.6-0.5-0.8c-0.1-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.6-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.7-0.7-1-0.7c-3.1,0.1-1.1,0-1.3,0  c-1.3,0.1-1.9-0.1-3.1,0.4c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.4c-0.6,0.2-1.9-0.2-1.9-0.2s-1.6-0.2-2.3-0.5c-0.7-0.3-2.2-1.7-2.2-1.7"/>
          <path id="V3svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M235.1,64.5c-1-1.1-5.2-0.2-5.2-0.2l-6.9-0.2l-8.7-0.4l-6.7,0.4l-7.7,1.1l-10.4,2.7l-13.7,5.4l-8.9,3.7l-5.7,3.1l-3.3,1.7l-2.6,1.9  l-1.7,1.5l-0.9,0.3l0.6,3.1l-0.4,5l-1,6.3v8.3l0.4,6.5l0.9,3.6l0.2,2.7l0.3,2.2l0.4,3l0.9,4.1v5.2l0.4,12.8l0.2,12.1l-0.2,6l-0.6,5  l-0.7,6.1l-1,4.6l-0.9,4.3l-3.7,10.3l-5,11l-3.1,6.1l-2.7,8.7l-1.3,5.2l-2.3,4.8l-2,5l-2.8,4.8l-2.8,4l-3.1,2.7l-6.1,2.2l-10,2.6  l-5.7,1.3l-5.2,0.6l-5.2,0.7c0,0-3.6,1-5.2,1.1c-0.9,0.1-2.4-0.6-3,0.2c-0.7,0.9,1.5,2.9,0.7,3.7c-0.4,0.4-1.7-0.3-1.7-0.3  s-1.1-0.6-1.7-0.7c-0.6-0.1-2.3,0.3-2.3,0.3l-6,0.6h-2.6H67l-6.5,1.9l-5.1-0.1c0,0-1.5-0.2-1.9,0.1c-0.5,0.4-0.8,1.1-1.3,1.5  c-0.2,0.2-0.8,1.2-1,1.5c-0.6,0.6-1.1,2.7-1.1,3.1c-0.2,1.2-0.6,3-0.6,4.3c0,1-0.1,1.9-0.2,2.2c-0.1,0.5,0.1,2.8,0.4,3.1  c0.4,0.4,1.4,0.3,1.9,0.6c0.4,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.9,0.9c0.2,0.1,0.2,0,0.4,0.1c0.5,0.2,0.9,0.8,1.1,1.3c0.5,1,1.4,1.6,2.2,2.4  c0.6,0.7,1.3,1.8,1.7,2.6c0.2,0.5,0.6,1.1,0.7,1.7c0.2,1,0.1,2.3-0.3,3.1c-0.2,0.7-1.1,1.5-1.5,2.2c-0.8,1.4-1.5,3.4-2.3,4.8  c-0.4,0.7-1,1.7-1.3,2.4c-0.2,0.6-0.7,1.4-0.8,2.2c-0.2,1.4,0.2,5.1,0.2,5.1v2.2c0,0,0.1,1.3,0.2,1.8c0.2,0.6,0.6,1.2,0.6,1.8  c0,1-0.2,2.3,0,3.3c0.1,0.5,0.6,1,0.7,1.5c0.2,0.7-0.1,1.7,0.2,2.4c0.2,0.8,0.8,1.9,1.3,2.6c0.4,0.6,1,1.5,1.5,2c1,1,2.7,2,4,2.7  c1,0.6,2.3,1.3,3.4,1.5c1.9,0.5,6.7,0.4,6.7,0.4h5c0,0,5.6,0.3,7.8-0.5c0.9-0.3,2.5-1.6,2.5-1.6s1.1-1.3,1.7-1.7  c0.8-0.6,2-1.3,3-1.5c0.9-0.3,2.2-0.3,3.1-0.4c2.4-0.2,5.7,0.3,8.2-0.2c0.6-0.2,1.5-0.6,2.2-0.9c1.6-0.5,5.4-1,5.4-1l6.3-0.7  l10.4-2.8l6.3-2.4l9.1-4.6l6-2.8l3.7-2.6l4.6-3.4l4.4-4.1l3-3.3l2.7-3.9l2.6-6.1c0,0,1.8-7.5,3-10.7c0.5-1.3,1.9-4.3,1.9-4.3  s1.4-2.3,1.8-3.3c1.1-2.7,2-6.5,3.1-9.2c0.8-2.1,3.1-6.9,3.1-6.9l1.7-3.4l2.3-3.7c0,0,1.6-2.7,2.3-3.9c1-1.5,2.1-3.6,3.1-5.2  c1-1.5,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8s1.6-2.5,2.4-3.4c1.5-1.6,3.6-3.6,5.2-5c1-0.7,2.3-1.4,3.3-2c1-0.6,2.6-1.4,3.7-1.9c1.7-0.7,5.7-2.3,5.7-2.3  l2.8-2c0,0,1.2-0.6,1.5-1c0.2-0.5-0.2-1.2,0-1.7c0.2-0.3,0.6-0.8,0.9-0.7c0.4,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.6,1.1c0.2,0.4,0.7,0.7,1.2,0.8  c0.8,0.2,0.8-1.3,1-2c0.4-1,0.4-1.9,0.4-2.7c0.1-1.6,0-2.7,0.1-4.5c0-0.5-0.6-1.9-0.6-2.3c0.1-0.9-0.9-3.1-0.9-3.1l-1.1-3  c0,0-0.8-1.9-1.1-2.7c-0.2-0.5-0.7-1.1-0.7-1.7c0-0.4,0.3-1.1,0.7-1.1c0.2,0,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.6c0.5,0.6,1.5,1.9,1.5,1.9l1.7,1  c0,0,1.6-0.1,2.3-0.3c0.6-0.2,1.4-1,2-1.3c0.6-0.2,1.5-0.2,2-0.6c0.3-0.2,0.4-0.8,0.7-1c0.6-0.3,1.6,0,2.3,0.2  c0.5,0.2,1.5,0.7,1.5,0.7s1.5,0.1,2-0.2c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.6,1-1c0.2-0.5-0.1-1.3,0-1.9c0.1-0.5,0.3-1,0.6-1.5c0.2-0.3,0.8-0.4,1-0.7  c0.2-0.3,0-0.8,0-1.1c0-2.3,0.2-7.6,0.2-7.6s-0.3-3.6,0.2-5.2c0.2-0.5,0.4-1.2,0.9-1.5c0.4-0.2,1.2,0.3,1.5,0  c0.6-0.5,0.4-2.6,0.4-2.6s0.2-4.4-0.2-6c-0.2-0.6-1-1.3-1.7-1.5c-0.5-0.2-1.1,0.2-1.5,0.3c-0.5,0-1.1,0-1.5-0.2  c-0.5-0.2-0.9-1-1.5-1c-0.6,0-1.1,0.8-1.7,1c-0.2,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.7,0c-0.4-0.3-0.4-1.2-0.4-1.7c-0.1-1,0.9-3.5,0-3.1  c-0.2,0.1-1,0-1.3-0.3c-0.6-0.6-0.4-2.7-0.4-2.7l-0.6-2.5l-2.4-19.3l-0.2-4.1l-0.2-4.4l-0.5-7.7l0.2-6.9l0.2-7.3l0.9-8.2l1.3-7.7  l0.9-6.9c0,0,0.5-3.7,1-5.2c0.4-1.4,1.5-3,2-4.3c0.4-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.1-2.2C235.2,65.6,235.8,65.3,235.1,64.5z"/>
      </svg>
  </defs>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much !

Comment: @Myk Ado:  you're welcome. But you should also consider a js approach, unless you really need to store/submit selections as form data – as suggested by [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71925706/multiple-checkboxes-for-multiple-paths-of-one-svg/71927761#answer-71927841)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that instead of 3 objects you need to place several hundreds or thousands of objects.
For example, when you want to process a real map of a country or the world.
Creating a thousand checkboxes and a label for them will be very laborious and easy to get confused.

I propose a solution based on SVG + JS and using the `<title>` tag to display information when hovering over the selected object:

```
<g>    
    <title>   "UT" - Utah
      State capital city - Salt Lake City
      Population
      City  186,440
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  200,591
      </title>
      <path id="UT"  class="Vsvg" d="M726.5,26.1l-83.7-11.9
        l20.6-112.5l46.8,8.7l-1.5,10.6l-2.3,13.2l7.8,0.9l16.4,1.8l8.2,0.9L726.5,26.1z"/>
</g>
```

To display information, hold the cursor on the selected object

```js
document.querySelectorAll('path.state').forEach(path => {
  path.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    if (path.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('g:last-child') !== path.parentNode)
      path.parentNode.parentNode.append(path.parentNode);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
width:50vw;
height:50vh;
}
.Vsvg {
fill:white;
stroke:dodgerblue;
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box: fill-box;
transition:  1s;
}

:hover.Vsvg {
 fill:dodgerblue;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:1px;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
 transform: scale(1.0.5); 
 }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
<svg id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 290.5 366.2">
    <defs>  
      <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs> 
      <g>
      <title>   CA" - California
      State capital city - Sacramento
      Population
      City  466,488
      Estimate (2018)   508,529
      </title>
          <path id="V1svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M249.3,38.1c-6.5,8.6-14.9,21.8-14.1,25.6c0.2,1.1-10.7,0.1-14.4,0.1c-3.4-0.1-8-0.2-11.3,0.2c-2.8,0.3-9.1,1.2-9.1,1.2l-10.2,2.8  l-11,4.1l-12.7,5.2l-8.6,4.5l-8.6,6.5l-8.2,7.3l-4.5,8.2l-2.8,9l-4.5,19.9l-2.4,8.2l-2,4.5l-0.8,3.6l-0.8,7.3l-0.8,9.4l-0.8,4.9  l-2.4,3.6l-6.9,3.2c0,0-3.3,0.2-4.5,0.8c-0.5,0.2-1,0.7-1.2,1.2c-0.2,0.6,0.1,1.5-0.2,1.9c-0.6,1-1.8,1.5-3.1,2.2  c-1.4,0.7-2.4,1.2-3.6,1.2c-0.7,0-2.1,0.1-2.8,0.1c-1,0-2.3,0-3.2,0c-1.1,0-2.6-0.2-3.6-0.4c-0.9-0.2-1.9-0.8-2.8-0.8  c-1.2,0-1.5-0.4-1.7-0.1c-1.7,1.5-2.7,2.8-2.7,2.8l-3.2,2.8l-5.7,6.9l-8.6,13.5l-3.2,4.5l-7.8,2.8l-7.8,1.6l-4.5,4.5l-3.6,3.6  c0,0-2.1,3.6-3.6,3.6c-1.8,0.2-4.9-3.2-4.9-3.2l-1.6-2.4l-0.4-2l-0.4-3.2c0,0-0.2-1.5,0-2c0.2-1.2,1.6-3.6,1.6-3.6l2-3.2  c0,0,1.2-1,1.8-1.6c0.6-0.5,1.9-1.7,1.9-1.7l1.6-1.6l1.6-1.6c0,0,3.4-6,4.9-8.6c2.7-4.8,9.4-15.9,9.4-15.9l3.2-4.9l1.6-2l2.8-3.6  l0.4-3.6v-3.6v-2.4l-1.3-3.1l-2-4.1l-0.8-4.9v-4.1l3.2-10.2l6.1-14.6c0,0,2.1-5.3,3.1-7.8c1-2.4,3.1-8.2,3.1-8.2l7.3-17.9l6.9-9.8  l6.5-8.2l12.3-7.8l14.3-8.2l23.2-8.6L158,39l28.2-1.6l20.4-0.8l27.3-0.8l9.4,0.3C243.3,36.1,250.5,36.5,249.3,38.1z"/>
         </g>
       <g>
      <title>   "NV" - Nevada
      State capital city - Carson City
      Population
      City  55,274
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  55,414
      </title>       
          <path id="V2svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M35.1,230.6l6.5-7.1c0,0,2.2-2.4,3.3-3.5c0.4-0.4,1-1.2,1.5-1.3c2-0.5,7.6-1.5,7.6-1.5l8.2-2.8l12.4-19.5l5.3-5.7l5.3-4.9l1-0.6  l5.7,1.6l6.9-0.2h1.9l4.7-2.3c0,0,0.9-0.9,1-1.5c0.2-0.4,0-1.5,0-1.5s0.3-1,0.6-1.3c0.7-0.6,3.1-1,3.1-1s2-0.2,2.7-0.4  c1.9-0.6,4.5-1.5,6.1-3.1c1-1,2.2-2.5,2.6-3.9c0.7-2.2,1.2-7.5,1.2-7.5l1-13.2l1.5-5.1l1.6-3.6l1.6-5.1l1.6-6.3l2-9.4  c0,0,2.6-11.5,4.5-16.1c0.6-1.5,1.8-3.1,2.5-4.5c0.6-1,1.2-2.7,2-3.6c1.2-1.5,5.1-4.3,5.1-4.3l3.6-3.6c0,0,2.7-2.7,2.8-2.3  c0.6,1.5,0,8.4,0,8.4l-0.4,2.8l-0.4,2.3l-0.2,7.1l0.4,9.2l0.8,3.5c0,0,0.5,4.2,0.7,6.1c0.2,1.6,0.9,5.5,0.9,5.5l0.2,6.9l0.4,8.8v9.2  v11l-1.2,11c0,0-0.6,3.4-1,4.4c-0.5,1.1-0.8,4.1-0.8,4.1s-1.5,4.8-2.2,6.8c-1,2.9-4,9.3-4,9.3l-3.2,6.9l-2,4.1l-2,5.5l-2.4,8.8  l-3.6,9c0,0-2.7,4.7-3.8,6.9c-0.6,1-1.6,2.3-2.3,3.2c-0.9,0.9-2,1.9-3.1,2.7c-1,0.7-3.1,1.5-4.3,2c-3.4,1.2-11,2.9-11,2.9l-7.9,1.9  l-8.2,0.8l-5.7,1.2c0,0-1.7,0.3-2.4,0.4c-0.4,0-1-0.2-1.2,0c-0.8,0.7,0.8,2.5,0.4,3.6c-0.2,0.6-1.9-0.6-1.9-0.6l-1.9-0.4l-2.8,0.4  l-6.7,0.4H67l-2.4,0.8l-2,0.6l-2.4,0.6l-3.2-0.2c0,0-2.3,0-3.2,0c-0.8,0-1.9,0-2.7,0c-0.2,0-0.6,0.2-0.8,0c-0.6-0.4-1-1.5-1.2-2.3  c-0.1-0.3,0-1,0-1s-0.2-0.7-0.4-1c-0.2-0.4-1.2-1-1.2-1s-0.8-0.3-1-0.6c-0.2-0.3-0.1-1.4-0.1-1.4s0-1,0.1-1.5  c0.2-0.7,0.7-1.9,0.7-2.3c0.1-0.6,0.8-2.2,0.8-2.4c0.2-1,1.9-8.6,1.5-11.6c-0.1-0.7-0.3-1.5-0.5-2.1c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.8-0.2-1.1  c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.7c0-0.1-0.3-0.6-0.5-0.8c-0.1-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.6-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.7-0.7-1-0.7c-3.1,0.1-1.1,0-1.3,0  c-1.3,0.1-1.9-0.1-3.1,0.4c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.4c-0.6,0.2-1.9-0.2-1.9-0.2s-1.6-0.2-2.3-0.5c-0.7-0.3-2.2-1.7-2.2-1.7"/>
        </g>    
          <g>
      <title>  "UT" - Utah
      State capital city - Salt Lake City
      Population
      City  186,440
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  200,591
      </title>
          <path id="V3svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M235.1,64.5c-1-1.1-5.2-0.2-5.2-0.2l-6.9-0.2l-8.7-0.4l-6.7,0.4l-7.7,1.1l-10.4,2.7l-13.7,5.4l-8.9,3.7l-5.7,3.1l-3.3,1.7l-2.6,1.9  l-1.7,1.5l-0.9,0.3l0.6,3.1l-0.4,5l-1,6.3v8.3l0.4,6.5l0.9,3.6l0.2,2.7l0.3,2.2l0.4,3l0.9,4.1v5.2l0.4,12.8l0.2,12.1l-0.2,6l-0.6,5  l-0.7,6.1l-1,4.6l-0.9,4.3l-3.7,10.3l-5,11l-3.1,6.1l-2.7,8.7l-1.3,5.2l-2.3,4.8l-2,5l-2.8,4.8l-2.8,4l-3.1,2.7l-6.1,2.2l-10,2.6  l-5.7,1.3l-5.2,0.6l-5.2,0.7c0,0-3.6,1-5.2,1.1c-0.9,0.1-2.4-0.6-3,0.2c-0.7,0.9,1.5,2.9,0.7,3.7c-0.4,0.4-1.7-0.3-1.7-0.3  s-1.1-0.6-1.7-0.7c-0.6-0.1-2.3,0.3-2.3,0.3l-6,0.6h-2.6H67l-6.5,1.9l-5.1-0.1c0,0-1.5-0.2-1.9,0.1c-0.5,0.4-0.8,1.1-1.3,1.5  c-0.2,0.2-0.8,1.2-1,1.5c-0.6,0.6-1.1,2.7-1.1,3.1c-0.2,1.2-0.6,3-0.6,4.3c0,1-0.1,1.9-0.2,2.2c-0.1,0.5,0.1,2.8,0.4,3.1  c0.4,0.4,1.4,0.3,1.9,0.6c0.4,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.9,0.9c0.2,0.1,0.2,0,0.4,0.1c0.5,0.2,0.9,0.8,1.1,1.3c0.5,1,1.4,1.6,2.2,2.4  c0.6,0.7,1.3,1.8,1.7,2.6c0.2,0.5,0.6,1.1,0.7,1.7c0.2,1,0.1,2.3-0.3,3.1c-0.2,0.7-1.1,1.5-1.5,2.2c-0.8,1.4-1.5,3.4-2.3,4.8  c-0.4,0.7-1,1.7-1.3,2.4c-0.2,0.6-0.7,1.4-0.8,2.2c-0.2,1.4,0.2,5.1,0.2,5.1v2.2c0,0,0.1,1.3,0.2,1.8c0.2,0.6,0.6,1.2,0.6,1.8  c0,1-0.2,2.3,0,3.3c0.1,0.5,0.6,1,0.7,1.5c0.2,0.7-0.1,1.7,0.2,2.4c0.2,0.8,0.8,1.9,1.3,2.6c0.4,0.6,1,1.5,1.5,2c1,1,2.7,2,4,2.7  c1,0.6,2.3,1.3,3.4,1.5c1.9,0.5,6.7,0.4,6.7,0.4h5c0,0,5.6,0.3,7.8-0.5c0.9-0.3,2.5-1.6,2.5-1.6s1.1-1.3,1.7-1.7  c0.8-0.6,2-1.3,3-1.5c0.9-0.3,2.2-0.3,3.1-0.4c2.4-0.2,5.7,0.3,8.2-0.2c0.6-0.2,1.5-0.6,2.2-0.9c1.6-0.5,5.4-1,5.4-1l6.3-0.7  l10.4-2.8l6.3-2.4l9.1-4.6l6-2.8l3.7-2.6l4.6-3.4l4.4-4.1l3-3.3l2.7-3.9l2.6-6.1c0,0,1.8-7.5,3-10.7c0.5-1.3,1.9-4.3,1.9-4.3  s1.4-2.3,1.8-3.3c1.1-2.7,2-6.5,3.1-9.2c0.8-2.1,3.1-6.9,3.1-6.9l1.7-3.4l2.3-3.7c0,0,1.6-2.7,2.3-3.9c1-1.5,2.1-3.6,3.1-5.2  c1-1.5,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8s1.6-2.5,2.4-3.4c1.5-1.6,3.6-3.6,5.2-5c1-0.7,2.3-1.4,3.3-2c1-0.6,2.6-1.4,3.7-1.9c1.7-0.7,5.7-2.3,5.7-2.3  l2.8-2c0,0,1.2-0.6,1.5-1c0.2-0.5-0.2-1.2,0-1.7c0.2-0.3,0.6-0.8,0.9-0.7c0.4,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.6,1.1c0.2,0.4,0.7,0.7,1.2,0.8  c0.8,0.2,0.8-1.3,1-2c0.4-1,0.4-1.9,0.4-2.7c0.1-1.6,0-2.7,0.1-4.5c0-0.5-0.6-1.9-0.6-2.3c0.1-0.9-0.9-3.1-0.9-3.1l-1.1-3  c0,0-0.8-1.9-1.1-2.7c-0.2-0.5-0.7-1.1-0.7-1.7c0-0.4,0.3-1.1,0.7-1.1c0.2,0,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.6c0.5,0.6,1.5,1.9,1.5,1.9l1.7,1  c0,0,1.6-0.1,2.3-0.3c0.6-0.2,1.4-1,2-1.3c0.6-0.2,1.5-0.2,2-0.6c0.3-0.2,0.4-0.8,0.7-1c0.6-0.3,1.6,0,2.3,0.2  c0.5,0.2,1.5,0.7,1.5,0.7s1.5,0.1,2-0.2c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.6,1-1c0.2-0.5-0.1-1.3,0-1.9c0.1-0.5,0.3-1,0.6-1.5c0.2-0.3,0.8-0.4,1-0.7  c0.2-0.3,0-0.8,0-1.1c0-2.3,0.2-7.6,0.2-7.6s-0.3-3.6,0.2-5.2c0.2-0.5,0.4-1.2,0.9-1.5c0.4-0.2,1.2,0.3,1.5,0  c0.6-0.5,0.4-2.6,0.4-2.6s0.2-4.4-0.2-6c-0.2-0.6-1-1.3-1.7-1.5c-0.5-0.2-1.1,0.2-1.5,0.3c-0.5,0-1.1,0-1.5-0.2  c-0.5-0.2-0.9-1-1.5-1c-0.6,0-1.1,0.8-1.7,1c-0.2,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.7,0c-0.4-0.3-0.4-1.2-0.4-1.7c-0.1-1,0.9-3.5,0-3.1  c-0.2,0.1-1,0-1.3-0.3c-0.6-0.6-0.4-2.7-0.4-2.7l-0.6-2.5l-2.4-19.3l-0.2-4.1l-0.2-4.4l-0.5-7.7l0.2-6.9l0.2-7.3l0.9-8.2l1.3-7.7  l0.9-6.9c0,0,0.5-3.7,1-5.2c0.4-1.4,1.5-3,2-4.3c0.4-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.1-2.2C235.2,65.6,235.8,65.3,235.1,64.5z"/>
         </g> 
      </svg>
</div>
```

*One more example*

```js
document.querySelectorAll('path.Vsvg').forEach(path => {
  path.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    path.parentNode.parentNode.append(path.parentNode);
  });
});
```

```css
.Vsvg {
fill:white;
stroke:dodgerblue;
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box: fill-box;
transition:  1s;
}

:hover.Vsvg {
 fill:dodgerblue;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:2px;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
 transform: scale(1.5);
 
 }
```

```html
<body>
   <section id="map">

    <svg version="1.1"
       id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="467 -284 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
      <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
      <g>
      <title>"ID" - IDAHO
      State capital city - Boise
      Population - 228,790
      </title>
      <path id="ID"  class="Vsvg" d="
        M615.5-107.5l8.8-35.2l1.4-4.2l2.5-5.9l-1.3-2.3l-2.5,0.1l-0.8-1l0.5-1.1l0.3-3.1l4.5-5.5l1.8-0.5l1.1-1.1l0.6-3.2l0.9-0.7l3.9-5.8
        l3.9-4.3l0.2-3.8l-3.4-2.6l-1.5-4.4l13.6-63.3l13.5,2.5l-4.4,21.4l3.6,7.5l-1.6,4.7l2,4.6l3.1,1.3l3.8,9.6l3.5,4.4l0.5,1.1l3.3,1.1
        l0.4,2.1l-7,17.4l-0.2,2.6l2.6,3.3l0.9,0l4.9-3l0.7-1.1l1.6,0.7l-0.3,5.4l2.7,12.6l3.9,3.2l1.7,2.2l-0.7,4.1l1.1,2.8l1.1,1.1
        l2.5-2.4l2.8,0l2.9,1.3l2.8-0.7l3.8-0.2l4,1.6l2.7-0.3l0.5-3l2.9-0.8l1.3,1.5l0.4,2.9l1.4,1.2l-8.4,53.6
        C710.4-89.3,622.5-106,615.5-107.5z"/> 
        </g>
  <g>    
    <title>   "UT" - Utah
      State capital city - Salt Lake City
      Population
      City  186,440
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  200,591
      </title>
      <path id="UT"  class="Vsvg" d="M726.5,26.1l-83.7-11.9
        l20.6-112.5l46.8,8.7l-1.5,10.6l-2.3,13.2l7.8,0.9l16.4,1.8l8.2,0.9L726.5,26.1z"/>
</g>
      <g>    
    <title>   "AZ" - Arizona
      State capital city - Phoenix
      Population
      City  1,445,632
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  1,660,272
      </title>
      <path id="AZ" class="Vsvg" d="
        M611.9,98.6l-2.6,2.2l-0.3,1.5l0.5,1l18.9,10.7l12.1,7.6l14.7,8.6l16.8,10l12.3,2.4l25,2.7l17.3-119.1l-83.7-11.9l-3.1,16.4l-1.6,0
        l-1.7,2.6l-2.5-0.1l-1.3-2.7l-2.7-0.3l-0.9-1.1H628l-0.9,0.6l-1.9,1l-0.1,7l-0.2,1.7l-0.6,12.6l-1.5,2.2l-0.6,3.3l2.7,4.9l1.3,5.8
        l0.8,1l1,0.6l-0.1,2.3l-1.6,1.4l-3.4,1.7l-1.9,1.9l-1.5,3.7l-0.6,4.9l-2.9,2.7l-2.1,0.7l0.1,0.8l-0.5,1.7l0.5,0.8l3.7,0.6l-0.6,2.7
        l-1.5,2.2L611.9,98.6z"/>
</g>        
<g>    
    <title>   "NV" - Nevada
      State capital city - Carson City
      Population
      City  55,274
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  55,414
      </title>
      <path id="NV" class="Vsvg" d="M663.4-98.4
        L639.8,30.4l-1.8,0.3l-1.6,2.4l-2.4,0l-1.5-2.7l-2.6-0.4l-0.8-1.1l-1-0.1l-2.8,1.6l-0.3,6.8l-0.4,5.8l-0.3,8.6l-1.4,2.1l-2.4-1.1
        L551.3-51.5l19-67.6L663.4-98.4z"/>
</g>        
<g>    
    <title>   "OR" - Oregon
      State capital city - Salem
      Population
      City  154,637
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  173,442
      </title>
      <path id="OR" class="Vsvg" d="
        M615.7-108.5l8.9-34.8l1.1-4.2l2.4-5.6l-0.6-1.2l-2.5,0l-1.3-1.7l0.5-1.5l0.5-3.2l4.5-5.5l1.8-1.1l1.1-1.1l1.5-3.6l4-5.7l3.6-3.9
        l0.2-3.5l-3.3-2.5l-1.8-4.6l-12.7-3.6l-15.1-3.5l-15.4,0.1l-0.5-1.4l-5.5,2.1l-4.5-0.6l-2.4-1.6l-1.3,0.7l-4.7-0.2l-1.7-1.4
        l-5.3-2.1l-0.8,0.1l-4.3-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.2-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.7-0.8l0.2-7.8l-2.3-3.9l-4.1-0.6l-0.7-2.5l-2.4-0.5l-5.8,2.1l-2.3,6.5
        l-3.2,10l-3.2,6.5l-5,14.1l-6.5,13.6l-8.1,12.6l-1.9,2.9l-0.8,8.6l0.4,12.1L615.7-108.5z"/>
</g>     
     <g>
      <title>   "WA" - Washington Territory
      State capital city - Olympia
      Population
      City  46,478
      Estimate (2018)   52,555
      </title>
      <path id="WA" class="Vsvg"  d="
        M569.1-276.4l4.4,1.5l9.7,2.7l8.6,1.9l20,5.7l23,5.7l15.2,3.2l-13.6,63.6l-12.4-3.5l-15.5-3.6l-15.2,0l-0.5-1.3l-5.6,2.2l-4.6-0.7
        l-2.1-1.6L579-200l-4.7-0.1l-1.7-1.3l-5.3-2.1l-0.7,0.1l-4.4-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.3-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.8-0.9l0.1-7.7l-2.3-3.8l-4.1-0.6
        l-0.7-2.5l-2.3-0.5l-3.6,1.2l-2.3-3.2l0.3-2.9l2.7-0.3l1.6-4l-2.6-1.1l0.2-3.7l4.4-0.6l-2.7-2.7l-1.5-7.1l0.6-2.9v-7.9l-1.8-3.2
        l2.3-9.4l2.1,0.5l2.4,2.9l2.7,2.6l3.2,1.9l4.5,2.1l3.1,0.6l2.9,1.5l3.4,1l2.3-0.2v-2.4l1.3-1.1l2.1-1.3l0.3,1.1l0.3,1.8l-2.3,0.5
        l-0.3,2.1l1.8,1.5l1.1,2.4l0.6,1.9l1.5-0.2l0.2-1.3l-1-1.3l-0.5-3.2l0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.5v-2.3l1.8-3.6l-1.1-2.6l-2.4-4.9l0.3-0.8
        L569.1-276.4z M559.6-270.4l2-0.2l0.5,1.4l1.5-1.6h2.3l0.8,1.5l-1.5,1.7l0.6,0.8l-0.7,2l-1.4,0.4c0,0-0.9,0.1-0.9-0.2
        s1.5-2.6,1.5-2.6l-1.7-0.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.7,0.6l-1.5-2.3L559.6-270.4z"/>
  </g> 
  <g>
      <title>   "CA" - California
      State capital city - Sacramento
      Population
      City  466,488
      Estimate (2018)   508,529
      </title>
      <path id="CA" class="Vsvg" d="
        M611.7,98.2l3.9-0.5l1.5-2l0.5-2.9l-3.6-0.6l-0.5-0.7l0.5-2l-0.2-0.6l1.9-0.6l3-2.8l0.6-5l1.4-3.4l1.9-2.2l3.5-1.6l1.7-1.6l0.1-2.1
        l-1-0.6l-1-1.1l-1.2-5.8l-2.7-4.8l0.6-3.5l-2.4-1L551.3-51.5l18.9-67.6l-67.1-15.7l-1.5,4.7l-0.2,7.4l-5.2,11.8l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.1
        l-1.8,0.8l-1.5,4.2l-0.8,3.2l2.7,4.2l1.6,4.2l1.1,3.6l-0.3,6.5l-1.8,3.1l-0.6,5.8l-1,3.7l1.8,3.9l2.7,4.5l2.3,4.9l1.3,4l-0.3,3.2
        l-0.3,0.5v2.1l5.7,6.3l-0.5,2.4l-0.6,2.3l-0.6,1.9l0.2,8.2l2.1,3.7l1.9,2.6l2.7,0.5l1,2.7l-1.1,3.6l-2.1,1.6h-1.1l-0.8,3.9l0.5,2.9
        l3.2,4.4l1.6,5.3l1.5,4.7l1.3,3.1l3.4,5.8l1.5,2.6l0.5,2.9l1.6,1v2.4l-0.8,1.9l-1.8,7.1l-0.5,1.9l2.4,2.7l4.2,0.5l4.5,1.8l3.9,2.1
        h2.9l2.9,3.1l2.6,4.9l1.1,2.3l3.9,2.1l4.8,0.8l1.5,2.1l0.6,3.2l-1.5,0.6l0.3,1l3.2,0.8l2.7,0.2l3.2-1.7l3.9,4.2l0.8,2.3l2.6,4.2
        l0.3,3.2v9.4l0.5,1.8l10,1.5l19.7,2.7L611.7,98.2z M523.6,54.5l1.3,1.5l-0.2,1.3l-3.2-0.1l-0.6-1.2l-0.6-1.5L523.6,54.5z
         M525.5,54.5l1.2-0.6l3.6,2.1l3.1,1.2l-0.9,0.6l-4.5-0.2l-1.6-1.6L525.5,54.5z M546.2,74.3l1.8,2.3l0.8,1l1.5,0.6l0.6-1.5l-1-1.8
        l-2.7-2l-1.1,0.2V74.3z M544.7,82.9l1.8,3.2l1.2,1.9l-1.5,0.2l-1.3-1.2c0,0-0.7-1.5-0.7-1.9s0-2.2,0-2.2L544.7,82.9z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>

  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick example with JS without the extra elements in the svg etc and a little more flexible, left the checkboxes showing for example sake only, would need tweaking to make the events go both ways.

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('the-svg'),
      paths = svg.querySelectorAll('path');

handleChecked = (elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const thePiece = document.getElementById(`${e.srcElement.id}-checkbox`);
    thePiece ? thePiece.checked = !thePiece.checked : console.error(thePiece);
    elem.style.fill = thePiece.checked ? '#3F72AF' : '#ffffff';
  });
};

window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  if (paths.length) {
    for (i = 0, x = paths.length; i < x; ++i) {
      handleChecked(paths[i]);
    }    
  }
});
```

```css
.mySVG input[type=checkbox]{
    /*display: none;*/
}
.mySVG label{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.mySVG svg{
    fill:#F9F7F7;
    stroke: #112D4E;
    stroke-width: 5;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mySVG">
  <input type="checkbox" id="V1svg-checkbox" name="x">
  <input type="checkbox" id="V2svg-checkbox" name="x">
  <input type="checkbox" id="V3svg-checkbox" name="x">
  <label for="x">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 290.5 366.2" id="the-svg">
          <path id="V1svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M249.3,38.1c-6.5,8.6-14.9,21.8-14.1,25.6c0.2,1.1-10.7,0.1-14.4,0.1c-3.4-0.1-8-0.2-11.3,0.2c-2.8,0.3-9.1,1.2-9.1,1.2l-10.2,2.8  l-11,4.1l-12.7,5.2l-8.6,4.5l-8.6,6.5l-8.2,7.3l-4.5,8.2l-2.8,9l-4.5,19.9l-2.4,8.2l-2,4.5l-0.8,3.6l-0.8,7.3l-0.8,9.4l-0.8,4.9  l-2.4,3.6l-6.9,3.2c0,0-3.3,0.2-4.5,0.8c-0.5,0.2-1,0.7-1.2,1.2c-0.2,0.6,0.1,1.5-0.2,1.9c-0.6,1-1.8,1.5-3.1,2.2  c-1.4,0.7-2.4,1.2-3.6,1.2c-0.7,0-2.1,0.1-2.8,0.1c-1,0-2.3,0-3.2,0c-1.1,0-2.6-0.2-3.6-0.4c-0.9-0.2-1.9-0.8-2.8-0.8  c-1.2,0-1.5-0.4-1.7-0.1c-1.7,1.5-2.7,2.8-2.7,2.8l-3.2,2.8l-5.7,6.9l-8.6,13.5l-3.2,4.5l-7.8,2.8l-7.8,1.6l-4.5,4.5l-3.6,3.6  c0,0-2.1,3.6-3.6,3.6c-1.8,0.2-4.9-3.2-4.9-3.2l-1.6-2.4l-0.4-2l-0.4-3.2c0,0-0.2-1.5,0-2c0.2-1.2,1.6-3.6,1.6-3.6l2-3.2  c0,0,1.2-1,1.8-1.6c0.6-0.5,1.9-1.7,1.9-1.7l1.6-1.6l1.6-1.6c0,0,3.4-6,4.9-8.6c2.7-4.8,9.4-15.9,9.4-15.9l3.2-4.9l1.6-2l2.8-3.6  l0.4-3.6v-3.6v-2.4l-1.3-3.1l-2-4.1l-0.8-4.9v-4.1l3.2-10.2l6.1-14.6c0,0,2.1-5.3,3.1-7.8c1-2.4,3.1-8.2,3.1-8.2l7.3-17.9l6.9-9.8  l6.5-8.2l12.3-7.8l14.3-8.2l23.2-8.6L158,39l28.2-1.6l20.4-0.8l27.3-0.8l9.4,0.3C243.3,36.1,250.5,36.5,249.3,38.1z"/>
          <path id="V2svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M35.1,230.6l6.5-7.1c0,0,2.2-2.4,3.3-3.5c0.4-0.4,1-1.2,1.5-1.3c2-0.5,7.6-1.5,7.6-1.5l8.2-2.8l12.4-19.5l5.3-5.7l5.3-4.9l1-0.6  l5.7,1.6l6.9-0.2h1.9l4.7-2.3c0,0,0.9-0.9,1-1.5c0.2-0.4,0-1.5,0-1.5s0.3-1,0.6-1.3c0.7-0.6,3.1-1,3.1-1s2-0.2,2.7-0.4  c1.9-0.6,4.5-1.5,6.1-3.1c1-1,2.2-2.5,2.6-3.9c0.7-2.2,1.2-7.5,1.2-7.5l1-13.2l1.5-5.1l1.6-3.6l1.6-5.1l1.6-6.3l2-9.4  c0,0,2.6-11.5,4.5-16.1c0.6-1.5,1.8-3.1,2.5-4.5c0.6-1,1.2-2.7,2-3.6c1.2-1.5,5.1-4.3,5.1-4.3l3.6-3.6c0,0,2.7-2.7,2.8-2.3  c0.6,1.5,0,8.4,0,8.4l-0.4,2.8l-0.4,2.3l-0.2,7.1l0.4,9.2l0.8,3.5c0,0,0.5,4.2,0.7,6.1c0.2,1.6,0.9,5.5,0.9,5.5l0.2,6.9l0.4,8.8v9.2  v11l-1.2,11c0,0-0.6,3.4-1,4.4c-0.5,1.1-0.8,4.1-0.8,4.1s-1.5,4.8-2.2,6.8c-1,2.9-4,9.3-4,9.3l-3.2,6.9l-2,4.1l-2,5.5l-2.4,8.8  l-3.6,9c0,0-2.7,4.7-3.8,6.9c-0.6,1-1.6,2.3-2.3,3.2c-0.9,0.9-2,1.9-3.1,2.7c-1,0.7-3.1,1.5-4.3,2c-3.4,1.2-11,2.9-11,2.9l-7.9,1.9  l-8.2,0.8l-5.7,1.2c0,0-1.7,0.3-2.4,0.4c-0.4,0-1-0.2-1.2,0c-0.8,0.7,0.8,2.5,0.4,3.6c-0.2,0.6-1.9-0.6-1.9-0.6l-1.9-0.4l-2.8,0.4  l-6.7,0.4H67l-2.4,0.8l-2,0.6l-2.4,0.6l-3.2-0.2c0,0-2.3,0-3.2,0c-0.8,0-1.9,0-2.7,0c-0.2,0-0.6,0.2-0.8,0c-0.6-0.4-1-1.5-1.2-2.3  c-0.1-0.3,0-1,0-1s-0.2-0.7-0.4-1c-0.2-0.4-1.2-1-1.2-1s-0.8-0.3-1-0.6c-0.2-0.3-0.1-1.4-0.1-1.4s0-1,0.1-1.5  c0.2-0.7,0.7-1.9,0.7-2.3c0.1-0.6,0.8-2.2,0.8-2.4c0.2-1,1.9-8.6,1.5-11.6c-0.1-0.7-0.3-1.5-0.5-2.1c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.8-0.2-1.1  c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.7c0-0.1-0.3-0.6-0.5-0.8c-0.1-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.6-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.7-0.7-1-0.7c-3.1,0.1-1.1,0-1.3,0  c-1.3,0.1-1.9-0.1-3.1,0.4c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.4c-0.6,0.2-1.9-0.2-1.9-0.2s-1.6-0.2-2.3-0.5c-0.7-0.3-2.2-1.7-2.2-1.7"/>
          <path id="V3svg" class="Vsvg" d="  M235.1,64.5c-1-1.1-5.2-0.2-5.2-0.2l-6.9-0.2l-8.7-0.4l-6.7,0.4l-7.7,1.1l-10.4,2.7l-13.7,5.4l-8.9,3.7l-5.7,3.1l-3.3,1.7l-2.6,1.9  l-1.7,1.5l-0.9,0.3l0.6,3.1l-0.4,5l-1,6.3v8.3l0.4,6.5l0.9,3.6l0.2,2.7l0.3,2.2l0.4,3l0.9,4.1v5.2l0.4,12.8l0.2,12.1l-0.2,6l-0.6,5  l-0.7,6.1l-1,4.6l-0.9,4.3l-3.7,10.3l-5,11l-3.1,6.1l-2.7,8.7l-1.3,5.2l-2.3,4.8l-2,5l-2.8,4.8l-2.8,4l-3.1,2.7l-6.1,2.2l-10,2.6  l-5.7,1.3l-5.2,0.6l-5.2,0.7c0,0-3.6,1-5.2,1.1c-0.9,0.1-2.4-0.6-3,0.2c-0.7,0.9,1.5,2.9,0.7,3.7c-0.4,0.4-1.7-0.3-1.7-0.3  s-1.1-0.6-1.7-0.7c-0.6-0.1-2.3,0.3-2.3,0.3l-6,0.6h-2.6H67l-6.5,1.9l-5.1-0.1c0,0-1.5-0.2-1.9,0.1c-0.5,0.4-0.8,1.1-1.3,1.5  c-0.2,0.2-0.8,1.2-1,1.5c-0.6,0.6-1.1,2.7-1.1,3.1c-0.2,1.2-0.6,3-0.6,4.3c0,1-0.1,1.9-0.2,2.2c-0.1,0.5,0.1,2.8,0.4,3.1  c0.4,0.4,1.4,0.3,1.9,0.6c0.4,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.9,0.9c0.2,0.1,0.2,0,0.4,0.1c0.5,0.2,0.9,0.8,1.1,1.3c0.5,1,1.4,1.6,2.2,2.4  c0.6,0.7,1.3,1.8,1.7,2.6c0.2,0.5,0.6,1.1,0.7,1.7c0.2,1,0.1,2.3-0.3,3.1c-0.2,0.7-1.1,1.5-1.5,2.2c-0.8,1.4-1.5,3.4-2.3,4.8  c-0.4,0.7-1,1.7-1.3,2.4c-0.2,0.6-0.7,1.4-0.8,2.2c-0.2,1.4,0.2,5.1,0.2,5.1v2.2c0,0,0.1,1.3,0.2,1.8c0.2,0.6,0.6,1.2,0.6,1.8  c0,1-0.2,2.3,0,3.3c0.1,0.5,0.6,1,0.7,1.5c0.2,0.7-0.1,1.7,0.2,2.4c0.2,0.8,0.8,1.9,1.3,2.6c0.4,0.6,1,1.5,1.5,2c1,1,2.7,2,4,2.7  c1,0.6,2.3,1.3,3.4,1.5c1.9,0.5,6.7,0.4,6.7,0.4h5c0,0,5.6,0.3,7.8-0.5c0.9-0.3,2.5-1.6,2.5-1.6s1.1-1.3,1.7-1.7  c0.8-0.6,2-1.3,3-1.5c0.9-0.3,2.2-0.3,3.1-0.4c2.4-0.2,5.7,0.3,8.2-0.2c0.6-0.2,1.5-0.6,2.2-0.9c1.6-0.5,5.4-1,5.4-1l6.3-0.7  l10.4-2.8l6.3-2.4l9.1-4.6l6-2.8l3.7-2.6l4.6-3.4l4.4-4.1l3-3.3l2.7-3.9l2.6-6.1c0,0,1.8-7.5,3-10.7c0.5-1.3,1.9-4.3,1.9-4.3  s1.4-2.3,1.8-3.3c1.1-2.7,2-6.5,3.1-9.2c0.8-2.1,3.1-6.9,3.1-6.9l1.7-3.4l2.3-3.7c0,0,1.6-2.7,2.3-3.9c1-1.5,2.1-3.6,3.1-5.2  c1-1.5,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8s1.6-2.5,2.4-3.4c1.5-1.6,3.6-3.6,5.2-5c1-0.7,2.3-1.4,3.3-2c1-0.6,2.6-1.4,3.7-1.9c1.7-0.7,5.7-2.3,5.7-2.3  l2.8-2c0,0,1.2-0.6,1.5-1c0.2-0.5-0.2-1.2,0-1.7c0.2-0.3,0.6-0.8,0.9-0.7c0.4,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.6,1.1c0.2,0.4,0.7,0.7,1.2,0.8  c0.8,0.2,0.8-1.3,1-2c0.4-1,0.4-1.9,0.4-2.7c0.1-1.6,0-2.7,0.1-4.5c0-0.5-0.6-1.9-0.6-2.3c0.1-0.9-0.9-3.1-0.9-3.1l-1.1-3  c0,0-0.8-1.9-1.1-2.7c-0.2-0.5-0.7-1.1-0.7-1.7c0-0.4,0.3-1.1,0.7-1.1c0.2,0,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.6c0.5,0.6,1.5,1.9,1.5,1.9l1.7,1  c0,0,1.6-0.1,2.3-0.3c0.6-0.2,1.4-1,2-1.3c0.6-0.2,1.5-0.2,2-0.6c0.3-0.2,0.4-0.8,0.7-1c0.6-0.3,1.6,0,2.3,0.2  c0.5,0.2,1.5,0.7,1.5,0.7s1.5,0.1,2-0.2c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.6,1-1c0.2-0.5-0.1-1.3,0-1.9c0.1-0.5,0.3-1,0.6-1.5c0.2-0.3,0.8-0.4,1-0.7  c0.2-0.3,0-0.8,0-1.1c0-2.3,0.2-7.6,0.2-7.6s-0.3-3.6,0.2-5.2c0.2-0.5,0.4-1.2,0.9-1.5c0.4-0.2,1.2,0.3,1.5,0  c0.6-0.5,0.4-2.6,0.4-2.6s0.2-4.4-0.2-6c-0.2-0.6-1-1.3-1.7-1.5c-0.5-0.2-1.1,0.2-1.5,0.3c-0.5,0-1.1,0-1.5-0.2  c-0.5-0.2-0.9-1-1.5-1c-0.6,0-1.1,0.8-1.7,1c-0.2,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.7,0c-0.4-0.3-0.4-1.2-0.4-1.7c-0.1-1,0.9-3.5,0-3.1  c-0.2,0.1-1,0-1.3-0.3c-0.6-0.6-0.4-2.7-0.4-2.7l-0.6-2.5l-2.4-19.3l-0.2-4.1l-0.2-4.4l-0.5-7.7l0.2-6.9l0.2-7.3l0.9-8.2l1.3-7.7  l0.9-6.9c0,0,0.5-3.7,1-5.2c0.4-1.4,1.5-3,2-4.3c0.4-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.1-2.2C235.2,65.6,235.8,65.3,235.1,64.5z"/>
      </svg>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I looked around a bit and tried it my self.
But as far as I now is there now way to do this, because to select the checkboxes you need to click somewhere in the viewbox of the svg and it can only be a square. So the one on top will always be selected, because its viewbox is over the other ones.

The only way around this is to figure out where the mouse is and put the svg that will be selected on top. I will try it and once I find a working solution I will edit or reply to this post.

Comment: You might want to try pointer-events="visiblePainted"

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript for this.
What you have to do is get the svg paths (by class or id) and add an event listener. Also, you need to get the checkboxes and assign them a value or true or false.

```html
    <!-- html starts here -->
    <svg>
      <path id='path1'>
    </svg>
    <input id='checkbox1' type='checkbox' />
```

```js
    // javascript starts here
    const firstPath = document.querySelector('#path1');
    const firstCheckbox = document.querySelector('#checobox1');
    
    firstPath.addEventListener('click', () => {
        firstCheckbox.checked = true;
    })
```

And you can make different combos so one path can enable 2 checkboxes, another can enable 3 and so on.